# Forwarding Apache SSL-Port to Web-App on localhost

Tags: ssl, apache-2.4, virtualhost, mod-rewrite, apache2

I'm struggeling for days now to route a subdomain with SSL to a local running vue app, specifically the [directus](https://directus.io) admin ui.

I've done this before, like with the tool monit, and it worked like a charm:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName monit.mydomain.com
  Redirect permanent / https://monit.mydomain.com
</VirtualHost>
    
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName monit.mydomain.com
  ProxyPass / http://localhost:2828/
  Include /etc/apache2/include.conf  <-- holds the key & certificate infos
</VirtualHost>
```

But with the directus admin ui, which is running on localhost:3000, this doesn't work, and apache gives me no error output at all, but shows some access logs, for example:

```
<IP> - - [14/Apr/2021:00:10:36 +0200] "GET /admin/js/chunk-vendors.8f8dd28c.js HTTP/1.1" 404 418 "https://admin.mydomain.com/app1/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.114 Safari/537.36 Edg/89.0.774.75"
```

The Browser simply shows:

```
GET https://admin.mydomain.com/admin/js/app.0038e4e5.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

The VirtualHost config I use is:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName admin.mydomain.com
  Redirect Permanent / https://admin.mydomain.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName admin.mydomain.com
  Include /etc/apache2/include.conf
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule ^/app1/(.*)$ http://localhost:3000/admin/$1 [proxy,last]
  ProxyPassReverse /app1http://127.0.0.1:3000/
</VirtualHost>
```

The reason for `/app1` is that later I want to route admin uis for several apps, each running on a different port, like `/app1 -> http://localhost:3000, /app2 -> http://localhost:3100`

Hope someone could give me a hint to solve this, thanks in advance!

Comment: first match trailing slashes, if source ends in / destination must also end the same.

Comment: `ProxyPassReverse /app1http://127.0.0.1:3000/` - You are also missing a _space_ between your arguments. (Or is that just a typo in your question?!)

Comment: @MrWhite: It's just a typo, in reality there is a space between /app1/ and http://locahost :-)

Comment: It works great if I use no subdir:

    ProxyPass / http://localhost:3000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3000/

But  if I add the subdir

    ProxyPass /app1/ http://localhost:3000/
    ProxyPassReverse /app1/ http://localhost:3000/

the browser redirects to `https://admin.mydomain.com/app1/admin/` and the errors like `https://admin.mydomain.com/admin/js/app.0038e4e5.js NOT FOUND` (notice the missing "app1") pops up.

A `curl --insecure -H 'Host: admin.mydomain.com' -is https://127.0.0.1/app1/` on the server returns the html document...

Comment: you mean the backend is redirecting you to /admin/ instead of app1? That would make more sense. Perhaps what you need is more specific proxypassreverse or even mod_proxy_html if the paths in the html you receive from the backend are not relative.

Comment: Yes the backend is redirecting me, the browser just shows it.
Thanks for the hint with the `mod_proxy_html`, I'll digg in and try!

Answer (score 1):

Why are you mixing RewriteRule with ProxyPassReverse? The following should do

```
ProxyPass /app1/ http://localhost:3000/admin/
ProxyPassReverse /app1/ http://localhost:3000/admin/
```

You could test on your reverse-proxy using the following

```
curl --insecure -H 'Host: admin.mydomain.com' -is https://127.0.0.1/app1/
```

Testing configurations using curl is more useful for troubleshooting in my experience, particularly when redirects are involved.

Comment: Why are you mixing RewriteRule with ProxyPassReverse?

As far as I remember, I tried every combination with the monit VirtualHost until it worked :-)

The ProxyPass-Directives above shows similar errors, but the curl statement gives an interesting output:

HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Wed, 14 Apr 2021 07:53:00 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Powered-By: Directus
Vary: Origin,Accept
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Content-Range
Location: ./admin/
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 30

Found. Redirecting to ./admin/

Comment: Also interesting is the browser error message

`GET https://admin.mydomain.com/admin/js/app.0038e4e5.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)`

but when i manually navigate to

`https://admin.mydomain.com/app1/admin/js/app.0038e4e5.js`

the browser shows the correct file...